# Get Operating System Info from a network host (LAN connected PC)

Tags: vba, excel, networking, operating-system

I am trying to get information from host connected to local network. Following code give operating system name like ***Microsoft Windows 10 Pro*** in my local pc. When I use a network pc name then prompt error `Access Denied`

[image]

My understanding is, it is not getting permission to collect information from that PC because there is no credential provided. So, my question is how to provide credential to these codes so that it can get permission to collect.

> Note: I have added exception `Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)` to windows firewall on remote PC.

```
Sub GetOS()
    If getOperatingSystem <> "" Then
        MsgBox getOperatingSystem()
    End If
End Sub

'------------- Function to get Operating System Info --------------

Public Function getOperatingSystem()
    Dim localHost       As String
    Dim objWMIService   As Variant
    Dim colOperatingSystems As Variant
    Dim objOperatingSystem As Variant

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    'localHost = "." 'Technically could be run against remote computers, if allowed
    localHost = "SCANNER-PC"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & localHost & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
    For Each objOperatingSystem In colOperatingSystems
        getOperatingSystem = objOperatingSystem.Caption '& " " & objOperatingSystem.Version
        Exit Function
    Next

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " & Err.Description
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Comment: What is the purpose of a For Each when you  Exit Function after first? Are you only interested in one result?

Comment: For each because if I can get information related `operating system` then I will also be able to get `disk drive`, `memory (RAM)`, `Processor` infoes as well. In that case if there multiple processor, disk or memory so that I can get all those information.

Comment: If it is possible to get information without `for  each` loop then it is fine. I am okay with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to pass credentials to WMI query. The following sub query information on remote PC using credentials.

```
Public Sub WMIQueryCRED()
Dim objSWbemLocator As Object
Dim objWMIService As Object
Dim colItems As Object
Dim strHost, strUserID, strPassword As String

strHost = "NetworkHost"
strUserID = "Domain\domainadmin"
strPassword = "Password"

    Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    Set objWMIService = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strHost, "root\cimv2", strUserID, strPassword)
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

    For Each objItem In colItems
        MsgBox objItem.Caption, vbInformation, "Successfull"
    Next

End Sub
```